# How to reuse my code for opening Accordions on click

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm currently using the following JS to open an accordion when an `<a>` tag is clicked. It uses the data-trigger value to determine what `<a>` to use.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-trigger="accordion"]').on('click', function(e) {
        var obj = $(this),
            accordionButtons = $('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation'),
            accordionPanels = $('.content.1', '[data-accordion]');

        if (obj.hasClass('toggle-open')) {
            accordionButtons.removeClass('active');
            accordionPanels.removeClass('active');
            obj.removeClass('toggle-open');
        } else {
            accordionButtons.addClass('active');
            accordionPanels.addClass('active');
            obj.addClass('toggle-open');
        }
        $('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation').trigger('click.fndtn.accordion');
        window.location.href = "#" + anchor;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

This above JS will open an accordion based on it's class. Below is an example of the link that is used to open the Accordion:

```
<a href="#protect-the-nhs" data-trigger="accordion">
```

An example of the code that it is referencing to open the accordion:

```
<div id="protect-the-nhs" class="content 1">
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me change this code so that I can reuse it for each Accordion on the page. Let me explain. The page has 5 different accordions, above I have used generic naming for the data-trigger and the accordion class "content 1".

I'd like to know if it is possible to somehow make it so I can use this code for each different accordion (So for example accordion 1 would have a class of "content 1", accordion 2 would have a class of "content 2" etc. However, for each accordion, there would also be a different link you have to click to open the accordion.

For example: Accordion one would rely on an `<a>` tag with `data-trigger="accordion1"` and it would open the accordion with `class="content 1"`.

I hope someone understands my ask and might be able to help! I've tried looking for something for this but haven't found anything. I'm still learning JS so TIA.

Thanks.

Comment: Something to note: CSS classes can not contain spaces. Your HTML is actually assigning 2 classes (content and 1) to your element, rather than a single class of "content 1". If you want to stick with these classnames, use a dash instead of space (ie, "content 1" becomes "content-1"

Comment: @mchandleraz I've done this on purpose to help with defining the specific class - It uses "content" class to display what's inside the accordion, then the "1" is just there to help JS define the specific div. I believe that's how it's working anyways.

Comment: the line that has `accordionButtons = $('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation'),` what is `.accordion-navigation`?

Comment: more specifically, can you show me what the variable declarations would look like if using the second accordion? (as in all 3 variables)

Comment: @TheBombSquad .accordion-navigation is just the main div that the content sits inside - Essentially the starting div for the accordions. Accordion 2 would be: `data-trigger="accordion-2"`, `.content.1` would change to `.content.2` and I believe `.accordion-navigation` would stay the same - It is a little confusing for me but I'm trying to understand it as much as I can.

Comment: oh, so JUST TO MAKE SURE, `.trigger('click.fndtn.accordion')` and `[data-accordion]` remains the same for each accordion? sry for the many questions but this is the LAST one

Comment: As far as I understand, yes @TheBombSquad

Answer (score 0):

My basic idea is to listen to the entire document, determine where got clicked and activate the correct accordion

PLEASE NOTE: I'm assuming that every `accordion` has a number right after it that corresponds to the content classes like `accordion1` `content 1`

```
document.onclick=function(e) {
    if(!e.path[0].dataset.trigger){return;} //i forgot that not every element has a data-trigger
    if(!e.path[0].dataset.trigger.startsWith('accordion')){return;} //listening to the whole document needs you have to ensure you aren't activating when you don't need to
    var n=e.path[0]["data-trigger"].split('accordion')[1]
    alert(n)
    var obj = e.path[0],
        accordionButtons = $('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation'),
        accordionPanels = $(`.content.${n}`, '[data-accordion]');

    if (obj.hasClass('toggle-open')) {
        accordionButtons.removeClass('active');
        accordionPanels.removeClass('active');
        obj.removeClass('toggle-open');
    } else {
        accordionButtons.addClass('active');
        accordionPanels.addClass('active');
        obj.addClass('toggle-open');
    }
    $('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation').trigger('click.fndtn.accordion');
    window.location.href = "#" + anchor;
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This seems to return the following error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: trigger is not defined".

Comment: it is why i was asking about the logistics.. that line above `window.location.href = "#" + anchor;` i don't REALLY know what's going on but if that's the error it means that `$('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation')` is probably null

Comment: wait, what was logged into the console? to ensure that i get the numbers correct(or to prove i got it wrong) I `console.log(n)` can you tell me what is logged before that error @LewisPickles?

Comment: To be fair my original code works for the first Accordion without that line so it might not actually be needed

Comment: so what ARE you triggering? u sure the line `$('[href*="#"]', '[data-accordion] .accordion-navigation').trigger('click.fndtn.accordion');` is useless?

Comment: I removed it and it definitely works without it - The part for opening the accordions happens when it adds the "active" class so yeah I don't think the trigger is needed actually.

Comment: ok well change `<a href="#protect-the-nhs" data-trigger="accordion">` to `<a href="#protect-the-nhs" data-trigger="accordion1">` and run it and see

Comment: trigger is not defined still on document.onclick

Comment: oh my I am so sorry, `e.path[0].data-trigger` is a WHOLE LOT DIFFERENT than `e.path[0]["data-trigger"]` that's a pure syntax error I pulled there, try it now

Comment: No worries, we are both learning :) - New error: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined at HTMLDocument.document.onclick

Comment: ok im running some code on my end to see what data is returned with `e.path[0]`

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy with other things too. Unfortunately doesn't seem to be doing anything - No errors either

Comment: @LewisPickles that means that the line that has the trigger function was important.. I'm changing the `console.log` to `alert` to see if it's triggering